# PHP: why are some internal functions missing from `get_defined_functions`?

Tags: php, function

PHP has a large number of batteries-included functions, e.g. [functions on arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). Some of these, like `each`, are present in `get_defined_functions()['internal']`. Others, like `reset` and many others, are not present at all. However, they are treated as functions in every other way: they are not documented as "language constructs" or keywords; I can call them using the "variable function" feature; `function_exists("reset")` returns true; if I try to redefine them (e.g. `function reset() { ... }`), I get an error about redeclaration, rather than a syntax error; and so on.

Why are these functions not listed by `get_defined_functions`? Are they not actually functions? If not, what are they? If they are functions, then what actually is it that `get_defined_functions` is listing? In either case, how do I list the things that don't appear in `get_defined_functions`?

Comment: Calling on the power of @Jon Skeet for this one.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that result, http://codepad.org/1ilxgNxi, you'll see `reset` at `['internal'][576]`. Or if you want to see different php versions: http://3v4l.org/Q33FX

Comment: No idea why this is marked as a duplicate, as it's obviously not, but whatever. The PHP mods around here seem to be extremely zealous as marking non-duplicates as duplicates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a short answer: Reset is present in get_defined_functions()['internal'].

Look at [1532] in this fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/h5n-ndx

Comment: Ah. Well. That's weird. I was using `var_dump`, you're using `print_r`. Time to find out what the difference is.

Comment: Aaaarrgh. Unbelievable. `var_dump` just chops out part of the serialized data structure: "(more elements)...". What's more, there's no way to tell it that I actually want it to print the thing I said I wanted it to print. Well, I won't use that from now on, then. Thanks!

Comment: @jameshfisher Also var_dump shows it: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fjt-rhy . Show your code that you use to output.